Upgrading from python 3.9 to 3.11 and received insecureRequest
I am upgrading from python3.9 to python3.11. I used the command pipenv install --python 3.11 and pipenv install -d
Now I receive this error in the jenkins pipeline build during the test app phase.
Captured stderr:

.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1063: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host

Without the python upgrade I see no errors. I'm reading the doc. I read that I can disable the warning but thats not the solution.
I dont want to disable because the upgrade from 3.9 to 3.11 caused the issue. I confirmed by redoing the build without the python upgrade and I received no errors.
I have a value to verify the cert.
 response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, verify='src/http_client/cert.pem')

Could the issue be that one of the packages does not have the correct version? How do I check the compatibility?
How do I fix this error without disabling the warning?

what does ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION say in each environment?

Is ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION something I need to install to print in each environment?

no, just import ssl first, it's in stdlib

I ran this command openssl version -a. Received this: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023)
